# SVN cli commit with escape characters

Tags: svn, command-line-interface

Using SVN at the command prompt I usually commit with the commit message in the same line.  For example:

`svn commit -m "Initial checkin"`

When I want to use shell reserved characters though such as the exclamation in:

`svn commit -m "It finally works!"`

It will kick out as an error because the shell is trying to do something other than just the svn command.  So I can escape the bang like:

`svn commit -m "woohoo\!"`

And then the commit goes through just fine, but now my commit message literally says `woohoo\!`.  Is there a way without using the message editor screen (I think it's vim or nano) for your message to get things like this to display properly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try single quotes - most (all?) unix shells leave them alone

```
svn commit -m 'It finally works!'
```